# Foreach loop - hide/show based on click event jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image]I have a list of records in my view using foreach. Now, I want to hide/show a textbox based on a click event on an image. My code is following:

```
@foreach (var dateitem in list)
{
    <td style="width:6%;" id="HoursTxt">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(modelitem => dateitem.Hours, new { id = string.Format("txtHours"), style = "width:60%;" })
        <img id=@(  dateitem.Project_Id + "_" + dateitem.Task_Id + "_" + "C" + "_img") src="~/Images/comment.png" onclick="GetComments(this.id);" />
        <div id=@(  dateitem.Project_Id + "_" + dateitem.Task_Id + "_" + "C") style="border:solid;display:none;">
            <textarea id=@(  dateitem.Project_Id + "_" + dateitem.Task_Id + "_" + "C" + "_text") style="position:absolute;" class="MyComment"></textarea>                                                                                                          
        </div>
    </td>
}
```

when I click on second, third images in that row, it shows textarea under only first textbox. My function is following:

```
function GetComments(id) {

    var prev; var strid = id;
    prev = strid.replace("_img", '');// alert(prev);

    //document.getElementById(prev).style.display = 'block';
    if (document.getElementById(prev).style.display == 'block') 
    {
        document.getElementById(prev).style.display = 'none';
    }
    else if (document.getElementById(prev).style.display == 'none') 
    {
        document.getElementById(prev).style.display = 'block';
    }

}
```

Can anyone help me to solve this? 
I want to hide/show textarea each time, below the particular textbox..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Can you share your final HTML output, or even better, put it on JsFiddle so we can more easily help you solve it...?

Comment: Do not post the source instead, please put the rendered HTML.

Comment: Your question title states 'jquery' but you have no jQuery code in your code samples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be very simple using jQuery.  First give your images a class eg: `prev`

Then in your document.ready function:

```
$('.prev').on('click', function() {
   // this is the current image clicked, 
   // .next() gets the sibling element that is directly after the current element
   // .toggle toggles the visibility
   $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

I'm not sure but try to send just `onclick="GetComments(this);` and in JS :

```
function GetComments(_this) {
    var targetedDiv = $(_this).parents('td').find('div');

    if ($(targetedDiv).css('display') == 'block') 
    {
        $(targetedDiv).css('display','none');
    }
    else
    {
        $(targetedDiv).css('display','block');
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have seen the question its actually hiding and displaying `div` containing `textarea` and not the `textarea` itself..

Comment: yes @GuruprasadRao.. you are right.Here is there, any other way to achieve this show/hide options?

Comment: @KaviSuja instead of targeting `textarea` from the above answer, target its `parent` or if you are using `jquery` then take that particular ids `next` element to hide or show `div`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao i am targeting parent div only not directly text area

Comment: @KaviSuja.. What `id` value you are getting after `replace`? Does that match its proper `id`?

Comment: You don't Have to get the id and split it ... just get the div from clicked img.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao and ZakariaAcharki now it's working thank you for  your time